# aws chime sdk -js mute attendee

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-chime-sdk, amazon-chime

I am using amazon-chime-sdk-js v3.14 is there any way to mute specific attendee and also mute all of attendee
also been using amazon-chime-sdk-component-library-react

I did tried sendData message way to mute but it isn't working

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.